# How to execute CUDA files in web server ( PHP )

Tags: php, linux, cuda

I'm doing a project on parallel processing, Here I'm trying to execute a CUDA binary file via php. I have uploaded the final binary to the /var/www/cuda/uploads/ folder, ( uploads folder has 777 Permission & mandelbrot.out was created in the same server via terminal ).

Now I'm trying to pass the command line arguments via POST requests,  Everything works fine, But I get an error saying ,

./mandelbrot.out : error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But I can run the same commands in the terminal & I get the correct output. I read a post there I was asked to give the full path of the file, I tried that too, Still no luck.

I tried searching the web, I did not find much resources, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment in which PHP runs is passed unmodified to its child processes (in your case, `./mandelbrot.out` unless you specifically modify it. PHP again inherits it from your HTTP server, e.g. Apache. Maybe your HTTP server does not have the path to `libcudart.so` in its shared library search path. For Apache, try adding, in `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH <absolute path to folder that contains libcudart.so>
```